# Using R data.tables, how can I update one table with values from another without using merge?

Tags: r, data.table

I have the following data tables in R:

```
Dt:
id     date       value
1      2017/1/1   1
1      2017/1/2   6
...
2      2017/1/1   5
...

Mult:
id     mult
1      .5
2      4
...
```

I want to multiply each value in Dt by the corresponding multiplier in Mult, based on id. Obviously, I could do:

```
Dt = merge(Dt,Mult,by='id')
Dt[,value := value * mult]
```

However, this would add a multiplier field to every row of Dt, which seems like a huge waste of time and space. Is there a way I can do something like:

```
Dt[,value := value * Mult[id==Dt$id]$mult]
```

Comment: maybe `Dt$value = Dt$value * Mult$mult[Dt$id]` ?

Comment: that seems to work in my simple test case, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This can be solved by an *update on join*:

```
Dt[, value := as.numeric(value)][Mult, on = "id", value := value * mult][]
```

> ```
>    id     date value
> 1:  1 2017/1/1   0.5
> 2:  1 2017/1/2   3.0
> 3:  2 2017/1/1  20.0
> ```

Note that `[, value := as.numeric(value)]` is required to ensure we get the proper result as `value` is of type integer and `mult` is of type numeric. So, the result of `value * mult` is of type numeric but would be stored piecewise in an integer column.

There is no issue if a new column is created:

```
Dt[Mult, on = "id", new_value := value * mult][]
```

> ```
>    id     date value new_value
> 1:  1 2017/1/1     1       0.5
> 2:  1 2017/1/2     6       3.0
> 3:  2 2017/1/1     5      20.0
> ```

#### Data

```
Dt <- fread(
  "id     date       value
1      2017/1/1   1
1      2017/1/2   6
2      2017/1/1   5"
)
```

Note that `fread()` has recognized `value` to be of type integer.

```
Mult <- fread(
  "id     mult
1      .5
2      4"
)
```

Note that `fread()` has recognized `mult` to be of type numeric.

Comment: And for safety vs columns with the same name in each table, could write as `x.value * i.mult`

Comment: Where did the x and i aliases come from? That's something I've been trying to figure out how to do in R for a while... Also, why is it . instead of $?

Comment: @Sinnombre, these are special symbols which can be used in an `j` expression of `data.table`. Please, see the *Advanced* sections in the documentation of `j` in `help("data.table")`.